# Bash script to calculate time elapsed

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a script in bash to calculate the time elapsed for the execution of my commands, consider:

```
STARTTIME=$(date +%s)
#command block that takes time to complete...
#........
ENDTIME=$(date +%s)
echo "It takes $($ENDTIME - $STARTTIME) seconds to complete this task..."
```

I guess my logic is correct however I end up with the following print out:

"It takes seconds to complete this task..."

Anything wrong with my string evaluation?

I believe bash variables are untyped, I would love if there is a "string to integer" method in bash nevertheless.

Comment: FYI: unix.stackexchange.com has a more generic question on this topic (measuring elpsed time in bash), see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314365

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Either `$(())` or `$[]` will work for computing the result of an arithmetic operation.  You're using `$()` which is simply taking the string and evaluating it as a command.  It's a bit of a subtle distinction.

As tink pointed out in the comments on this answer, `$[]` is deprecated, and `$(())` should be favored.

Comment: You may want to swap those two around, as bash 4.x man-page states that the **$[]** is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.

Answer (score 222):

I find it very clean to use the internal variable "$SECONDS"

`SECONDS=0 ; sleep 10 ; echo $SECONDS`

Comment: `$SECONDS` does indeed work for /bin/bash. It does not work for the /bin/dash, the default shell in Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: Downside to this solution is that it only measures whole seconds, i.e. not usable if you need sub-second precision.

Comment: @Czechnology yes, if you use `sleep 0.5` in above, the result is sometimes 0, sometimes 1 (at least by Bash 5.0.3).

Comment: ```start=`date +%s%N` ; end=`date +%s%N` ; echo $(( ($end - $start) ))``` **Gives you nanoseconds**

```start=`date +%s%N` ; end=`date +%s%N` ; echo $(( ($end - $start) / 1000 ))```
**Gives you microseconds**

```start=`date +%s%N` ; end=`date +%s%N` ; echo $(( ($end - $start) / 1000000 ))```
**Gives you milliseconds**

Answer (score 65):

You are trying to execute the number in the `ENDTIME` as a command. You should also see an error like  `1370306857: command not found`. Instead use the [arithmetic expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC34):

```
echo "It takes $((ENDTIME - STARTTIME)) seconds to complete this task..."
```

You could also save the commands in a separate script, `commands.sh`, and use time command:

```
time commands.sh
```

Answer (score 35):

You can use Bash's `time` keyword here with an appropriate format string

```
TIMEFORMAT='It takes %R seconds to complete this task...'
time {
    #command block that takes time to complete...
    #........
 }
```

Here's what the [reference says about `TIMEFORMAT`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-TIMEFORMAT):

> The value of this parameter is used as a format string specifying how the timing information for pipelines prefixed with the `time`
>   reserved word should be displayed. The ‘`%`’ character introduces an
>   escape sequence that is expanded to a time value or other information.
>   The escape sequences and their meanings are as follows; the braces
>   denote optional portions.
>
> ```
> %%
>
>     A literal ‘%’.
> %[p][l]R
>
>     The elapsed time in seconds.
> %[p][l]U
>
>     The number of CPU seconds spent in user mode.
> %[p][l]S
>
>     The number of CPU seconds spent in system mode.
> %P
>
>     The CPU percentage, computed as (%U + %S) / %R.
> ```
>
> The optional *p* is a digit specifying the precision, the number of fractional digits after a decimal point. A value of 0 causes no
>   decimal point or fraction to be output. At most three places after the
>   decimal point may be specified; values of *p* greater than 3 are changed
>   to 3. If *p* is not specified, the value 3 is used.
>
> The optional `l` specifies a longer format, including minutes, of the form *MMmSS.FFs.* The value of *p* determines whether or not the
>   fraction is included.
>
> If this variable is not set, Bash acts as if it had the value
>
> ```
> $'\nreal\t%3lR\nuser\t%3lU\nsys\t%3lS'
> ```
>
> If the value is null, no timing information is displayed. A trailing newline is added when the format string is displayed.

Comment: If you need to include backslash-escaped characters in the TIMEFORMAT variable you have to use a $ at the beginning. For example, TIMEFORMAT='\nreal: %3R' won't work, while TIMEFORMAT=$'\nreal: %3R' will.
The answer of course implies that, just wanted to make it more explicit.

Comment: @blaze9 Sure, it's called [ANSI-C quotes](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting), and its use is not limited to `TIMEFORMAT`: you can use it each time you want to include a backslash escape in any string. E.g., `a=$'hello\nworld'` and then `echo "$a"`.

Answer (score 19):

For larger numbers we may want to print in a more readable format. The example below does same as other but also prints in "human" format:

```
secs_to_human() {
    if [[ -z ${1} || ${1} -lt 60 ]] ;then
        min=0 ; secs="${1}"
    else
        time_mins=$(echo "scale=2; ${1}/60" | bc)
        min=$(echo ${time_mins} | cut -d'.' -f1)
        secs="0.$(echo ${time_mins} | cut -d'.' -f2)"
        secs=$(echo ${secs}*60|bc|awk '{print int($1+0.5)}')
    fi
    echo "Time Elapsed : ${min} minutes and ${secs} seconds."
}
```

Simple testing:

```
secs_to_human "300"
secs_to_human "305"
secs_to_human "59"
secs_to_human "60"
secs_to_human "660"
secs_to_human "3000"
```

Output:

```
Time Elapsed : 5 minutes and 0 seconds.
Time Elapsed : 5 minutes and 5 seconds.
Time Elapsed : 0 minutes and 59 seconds.
Time Elapsed : 1 minutes and 0 seconds.
Time Elapsed : 11 minutes and 0 seconds.
Time Elapsed : 50 minutes and 0 seconds.
```

To use in a script as described in other posts (capture start point then call the function with the finish time:

```
start=$(date +%s)
# << performs some task here >>
secs_to_human "$(($(date +%s) - ${start}))"
```

Answer (score 12):

Try the following code:

```
start=$(date +'%s') && sleep 5 && echo "It took $(($(date +'%s') - $start)) seconds"
```

Comment: why do people obsess with crazy one liners like this?

Comment: @MikeQ - I am glad they do!
Such knowledge of available tools.
We learn from these "haikus".

Answer (score 10):

This is a one-liner alternative to Mike Q's function:

```
secs_to_human() {
    echo "$(( ${1} / 3600 ))h $(( (${1} / 60) % 60 ))m $(( ${1} % 60 ))s"
}
```

Comment: Nice! I usually am very verbose with my bash code, this is cool.

Comment: Combining this with `SECONDS` from Lon Kaut's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31663949) and keeping mind that [$/${} is unnecessary on arithmetic variables](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2004) makes the code so short it could even be used inline: `echo "$((SECONDS/3600))h $(((SECONDS/60)%60))m $((SECONDS%60))s"`

Answer (score 3):

try using time with the elapsed seconds option:

`/usr/bin/time -f%e sleep 1` under bash.

or `\time -f%e sleep 1` in interactive bash.

see the time man page:

> Users  of  the  bash shell need to use an explicit path in order to run
>          the external time command and not the shell builtin variant. On  system
>          where time is installed in /usr/bin, the first example would become
>               /usr/bin/time wc /etc/hosts

and

```
FORMATTING THE OUTPUT
...
    %      A literal '%'.
    e      Elapsed  real  (wall  clock) time used by the process, in
                 seconds.
```

Comment: `/bin/time` isn't going to work here: OP mentions a _block_. So we really need the keyword `time` here.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old post and it seems that everybody like writing too much code here. But actually, you only need 3 lines of simple bash code in order to you can show properly the elapsed time in a well-formatted way.

```
START_TIME=$(date +%s)

# put your code here

ELAPSED=$(($(date +%s) - START_TIME))
printf "elapsed: %s\n\n" "$(date -d@$ELAPSED -u +%H\ hours\ %M\ min\ %S\ sec)"
```

This produces the following result:

```
elapsed: 0 hours 2 min 19 sec
```

**Test the code:**

```
START_TIME=$(date +%s)
ELAPSED=86399
printf "elapsed: %s\n\n" "$(date -d@$ELAPSED -u +%H\ hour\ %M\ min\ %S\ sec)"

elapsed: 23 hour 59 min 59 sec
```

If you would like to show the days as well, then you need to do a little trick in order for the day will be displayed properly:

```
 ELAPSED=86399
 printf "elapsed: %s\n\n" "$(date -d@$ELAPSED -u +%d\ days\ %H\ hour\ %M\ min\ %S\ sec)"
 elapsed: 01 days 23 hour 59 min 59 sec

 ELAPSED=86400
 elapsed: 02 days 00 hour 00 min 00 sec
```

As you can see the day is calculated on a wrong way, so you need to do a math operation in bash this way:

```
printf "elapsed: %s day %s\n\n" "$(($(date -d@$ELAPSED -u +%d)-1))" "$(date -d@$ELAPSED -u +%H\ hour\ %M\ min\ %S\ sec)"
elapsed: 1 day 00 hour 00 min 00 sec
```

The `\` character in the date-time pattern escapes the whitespace.

I hope that it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Combining internal variable "$SECONDS" in [Lon Kaut's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31663949/1455694) with ssc's one-liner under [Internal Server Error's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59096583/1455694):

```
SECONDS=0
sleep 2s
echo "Elapsed time: $((SECONDS/3600))h $(((SECONDS/60)%60))m $((SECONDS%60))s"
```

([$/${} is unnecessary on arithmetic variables](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2004))

Answer (score -2):

```
start=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S);
for x in {1..5};
do echo $x;
sleep 1; done;
end=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S);
elapsed=$(($end-$start));
ftime=$(for((i=1;i<=$((${#end}-${#elapsed}));i++));
        do echo -n "-";
        done;
        echo ${elapsed});
echo -e "Start  : ${start}\nStop   : ${end}\nElapsed: ${ftime}"

Start  : 20171108005304
Stop   : 20171108005310
Elapsed: -------------6
```

Answer (score -4):

```
    #!/bin/bash

    time_elapsed(){
    appstop=$1; appstart=$2

    ss_strt=${appstart:12:2} ;ss_stop=${appstop:12:2}
    mm_strt=${appstart:10:2} ;mm_stop=${appstop:10:2}
     hh_strt=${appstart:8:2} ; hh_stop=${appstop:8:2}
     dd_strt=${appstart:6:2} ; dd_stop=${appstop:6:2}
     mh_strt=${appstart:4:2} ; mh_stop=${appstop:4:2}
     yy_strt=${appstart:0:4} ; yy_stop=${appstop:0:4}

    if [ "${ss_stop}" -lt "${ss_strt}" ]; then ss_stop=$((ss_stop+60)); mm_stop=$((mm_stop-1)); fi
    if [ "${mm_stop}" -lt "0" ]; then mm_stop=$((mm_stop+60)); hh_stop=$((hh_stop-1)); fi
    if [ "${mm_stop}" -lt "${mm_strt}" ]; then mm_stop=$((mm_stop+60)); hh_stop=$((hh_stop-1)); fi
    if [ "${hh_stop}" -lt "0" ]; then hh_stop=$((hh_stop+24)); dd_stop=$((dd_stop-1)); fi
    if [ "${hh_stop}" -lt "${hh_strt}" ]; then hh_stop=$((hh_stop+24)); dd_stop=$((dd_stop-1)); fi

    if [ "${dd_stop}" -lt "0" ]; then dd_stop=$((dd_stop+$(mh_days $mh_stop $yy_stop))); mh_stop=$((mh_stop-1)); fi
    if [ "${dd_stop}" -lt "${dd_strt}" ]; then dd_stop=$((dd_stop+$(mh_days $mh_stop $yy_stop))); mh_stop=$((mh_stop-1)); fi

    if [ "${mh_stop}" -lt "0" ]; then mh_stop=$((mh_stop+12)); yy_stop=$((yy_stop-1)); fi
    if [ "${mh_stop}" -lt "${mh_strt}" ]; then mh_stop=$((mh_stop+12)); yy_stop=$((yy_stop-1)); fi

    ss_espd=$((10#${ss_stop}-10#${ss_strt})); if [ "${#ss_espd}" -le "1" ]; then ss_espd=$(for((i=1;i<=$((${#ss_stop}-${#ss_espd}));i++)); do echo -n "0"; done; echo ${ss_espd}); fi
    mm_espd=$((10#${mm_stop}-10#${mm_strt})); if [ "${#mm_espd}" -le "1" ]; then mm_espd=$(for((i=1;i<=$((${#mm_stop}-${#mm_espd}));i++)); do echo -n "0"; done; echo ${mm_espd}); fi
    hh_espd=$((10#${hh_stop}-10#${hh_strt})); if [ "${#hh_espd}" -le "1" ]; then hh_espd=$(for((i=1;i<=$((${#hh_stop}-${#hh_espd}));i++)); do echo -n "0"; done; echo ${hh_espd}); fi
    dd_espd=$((10#${dd_stop}-10#${dd_strt})); if [ "${#dd_espd}" -le "1" ]; then dd_espd=$(for((i=1;i<=$((${#dd_stop}-${#dd_espd}));i++)); do echo -n "0"; done; echo ${dd_espd}); fi
    mh_espd=$((10#${mh_stop}-10#${mh_strt})); if [ "${#mh_espd}" -le "1" ]; then mh_espd=$(for((i=1;i<=$((${#mh_stop}-${#mh_espd}));i++)); do echo -n "0"; done; echo ${mh_espd}); fi
    yy_espd=$((10#${yy_stop}-10#${yy_strt})); if [ "${#yy_espd}" -le "1" ]; then yy_espd=$(for((i=1;i<=$((${#yy_stop}-${#yy_espd}));i++)); do echo -n "0"; done; echo ${yy_espd}); fi

    echo -e "${yy_espd}-${mh_espd}-${dd_espd} ${hh_espd}:${mm_espd}:${ss_espd}"
    #return $(echo -e "${yy_espd}-${mh_espd}-${dd_espd} ${hh_espd}:${mm_espd}:${ss_espd}")
    }

    mh_days(){
    mh_stop=$1; yy_stop=$2; #also checks if it's leap year or not

    case $mh_stop in
     [1,3,5,7,8,10,12]) mh_stop=31
     ;;
     2) (( !(yy_stop % 4) && (yy_stop % 100 || !(yy_stop % 400) ) )) && mh_stop=29 || mh_stop=28
     ;;
     [4,6,9,11]) mh_stop=30
     ;;
    esac

    return ${mh_stop}
    }

    appstart=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S); read -p "Wait some time, then press nay-key..." key; appstop=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S); elapsed=$(time_elapsed $appstop $appstart); echo -e "Start...: ${appstart:0:4}-${appstart:4:2}-${appstart:6:2} ${appstart:8:2}:${appstart:10:2}:${appstart:12:2}\nStop....: ${appstop:0:4}-${appstop:4:2}-${appstop:6:2} ${appstop:8:2}:${appstop:10:2}:${appstop:12:2}\n$(printf '%0.1s' "="{1..30})\nElapsed.: ${elapsed}"

    exit 0


-------------------------------------------- return
Wait some time, then press nay-key...
Start...: 2017-11-09 03:22:17
Stop....: 2017-11-09 03:22:18
==============================
Elapsed.: 0000-00-00 00:00:01
```