# How to check execution time of a bash script that starts background processes

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing

I have a bash script which runs 4 different process in the background and you can see the code below:

```
declare -a arr=("seed_automation_data_1" "seed_automation_data_2" "seed_automation_data_3" "seed_automation_data_4")
command="bundle exec rake db:seed:"
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   $command$i &
done
```

This bash script is actually running a `rake task` in `rails framework`.

> $command$i &

This particular line is starting four different process in the background:-

```
bundle exec rake db:seed:seed_automation_data_1
bundle exec rake db:seed:seed_automation_data_2
bundle exec rake db:seed:seed_automation_data_3
bundle exec rake db:seed:seed_automation_data_4
```

Since there are four different process running in the background I am not able to know when the `bash script` is `FINISHED` or calculate the `execution-time` of it.

Is there a way I can print some statements which will show that the script is finished running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [`wait` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html) in `bash`. It simply waits for all child processes to finish. Then you can easily calculate the time elapsed e.g. using the `SECONDS` internal variable (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31663949/1544012)):

```
SECONDS=0

declare -a arr=("seed_automation_data_1" "seed_automation_data_2" "seed_automation_data_3" "seed_automation_data_4")
command="bundle exec rake db:seed:"
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
  $command$i &
done

wait
echo $SECONDS
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a job for GNU Parallel:

```
declare -a arr=("seed_automation_data_1" "seed_automation_data_2" "seed_automation_data_3" "seed_automation_data_4")
parallel --joblog - bundle exec rake db:seed:{} ::: "${arr[@]}"
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to. It can often replace a `for` loop.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

For security reasons it is recommended you use your package manager to install. But if you cannot do that then you can use this 10 seconds installation.

The 10 seconds installation will try to do a full installation; if that fails, a personal installation; if that fails, a minimal installation.

```
$ (wget -O - pi.dk/3 || lynx -source pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || \
   fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3 ) > install.sh
$ sha1sum install.sh | grep 883c667e01eed62f975ad28b6d50e22a
12345678 883c667e 01eed62f 975ad28b 6d50e22a
$ md5sum install.sh | grep cc21b4c943fd03e93ae1ae49e28573c0
cc21b4c9 43fd03e9 3ae1ae49 e28573c0
$ sha512sum install.sh | grep da012ec113b49a54e705f86d51e784ebced224fdf
79945d9d 250b42a4 2067bb00 99da012e c113b49a 54e705f8 6d51e784 ebced224
fdff3f52 ca588d64 e75f6033 61bd543f d631f592 2f87ceb2 ab034149 6df84a35
$ bash install.sh
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Comment: GNU Parallel is amazing and initially I was using that only but I noticed that using `&` is more time efficient.

Comment: @python Correct. As long as you do not care about mixed output and you do not have more jobs than your system can handle them all in parallel, '&' will be more efficient.